# How to categorize a select field with values from the same table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user can create a DeliveryCost where they specify title, cost_per_unit and the timing. All fields are unique apart from timing which comes from a constant. here is a relevant snippet

```
# Table name: delivery_costs
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  title         :string(255)
#  cost_per_unit :float
#  created_at    :datetime
#  updated_at    :datetime
#  timing        :string(255)
#

class DeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base


  TIMING_INSTALL='Install'
  TIMING_BREAKDOWN='Breakdown'
  TIMING_TRANSPORT='Fuel'

  TIMINGS=[TIMING_INSTALL,TIMING_BREAKDOWN,TIMING_TRANSPORT]

  has_many :job_delivery_costs
```

These records are then attached to a JobDeliveryCost, where further fields can be entered. When a user selects from these DeliveryCost titles, the timing is displayed for every instance of a title... not very pretty

```
= f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:timing), :label_method => :timing, :value_method => :id, label: false
= f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title), :label_method => :title, :value_method => :id, label: false
```

Surely there is a way I can group Delivery Cost Titles by Delivery Cost Timings, and apply it to both index actions and a drop down select menu action. I've looked about but not seen anything so far. I did something like this to generate an array,

```
@delivery_cost = DeliveryCost.all
 @delivery_cost = @delivery_cost.map {|c| c.timing}.uniq!
```

But this is of little value as it just creates a new array...

a little example of what i hope to achieve

```
 --install--
    foo
    bar
    foo
 --breakdown--
    blah
    cat
 --fuel--
    jimmy
    cricket
```

Help!

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: delivery_costs
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  title         :string(255)
#  cost_per_unit :float
#  created_at    :datetime
#  updated_at    :datetime
#  timing        :string(255)
#

class DeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base

  TIMING_INSTALL='Install'
  TIMING_BREAKDOWN='Breakdown'
  TIMING_TRANSPORT='Fuel'
  TIMINGS=[TIMING_INSTALL,TIMING_BREAKDOWN,TIMING_TRANSPORT]

  before_destroy :survive_if_jobs

  has_many :job_delivery_costs
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_delivery_costs

  scope :install, -> { where(:timing => 'Install') }
  scope :breakdown, -> { where(:timing => 'Breakdown') }
  scope :fuel, -> { where(:timing => 'Fuel') }

  validates :timing, inclusion: TIMINGS
  validates :cost_per_unit, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true

  def titles_by_timing
    self.pluck(:timing, :title).group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }
  end

  private

  def survive_if_jobs
    jobs.empty?
  end

end
```

i am getting unexpected keywork end error from the model, occuring somewhere in his suggested array pluck method

Error Message

app/models/delivery_cost.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

```
Extracted source (around line #5):

@delivery_cost = DeliveryCost.all <this being line 5
 @delivery_cost = @delivery_cost.map {|c| c.timing}.uniq!
 # get_title
 raise
```

added section of view

```
%td
                      = f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:timing), :label_method => :timing, :value_method => :id, label: false
                    %td
                      = f.select :title, grouped_options_for_select(DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing)
                    %td
                      = f.input :cost_per_unit, label: false
                    %td
                      = f.input :hour_count, label: false
                    %td
                      = f.input :quantity, label: false
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`grouped_options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_options_for_select), which takes either a nested array or a hash of arrays as input. I'll demonstrate both.

### Nested Array

Add a method to your `DeliveryCost` model that returns a nested array in the format of:

```
[["Install", ["foo", "bar"]], ["Breakdown", ["blah", "cat"]], ["Fuel", ["jimmy", "cricket"]]]
```

This is one of the formats permitted by `grouped_options_for_select`. One such method to get this format do that would be:

```
def self.titles_by_timing
  self.pluck(:timing, :title).group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }
end
```

To further explain the dense code above, I'll go through it function by function. `pluck(:timing, :title)` will return the timing and title of each row in your `delivery_timing` table. So using your example, it would return:

```
[["Install", "foo"], ["Install", "bar"], ["Breakdown", "blah"], ["Breakdown", "cat"], ["Fuel", "jimmy"], ["Fuel, "cricket"]]
```

Then, calling `group_by(&:first)` will make a hash of nested arrays with the key being the timing, and the value being all timing-title combinations. Using your example:

```
{ "Install" => [["Install", "foo"], ["Install", "bar"]], 
  "Breakdown" => [["Breakdown", "blah"], ["Breakdown", "cat"]], 
   "Fuel" => [["Fuel", "jimmy"], ["Fuel, "cricket"]] }
```

And calling the last part, `map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }`, turns each hash key value pair into an array with two elements. The first element will be the `timing`, and the second element will be the array of `title`s that have that `timing`. Using your example (note this is the same as the format at the top):

```
[["Install", ["foo", "bar"]], ["Breakdown", ["blah", "cat"]], ["Fuel", ["jimmy", "cricket"]]]
```

### Hash of Arrays

Using a hash of arrays is a bit simpler, I believe. Here's the format:

```
{ "Install" => ["foo", "bar"], "Breakdown" => ["blah", "cat"], "Fuel" => ["jimmy", "cricket"] }
```

Similarly, add a method to your `DeliveryCost` model to get the titles grouped by timings

```
def self.titles_by_timing
  self.pluck(:timing, :title).group_by(&:first).each { |_, v| v.map!(&:last) }
end
```

The first two steps (`pluck` and `group_by`) are the same as above, but the third step takes the hash of nested arrays, i.e. `{ "Install" => [["Install", "foo"], ["Install, "bar"]], ...`, and makes it a hash of arrays, where each array is simply the list of titles for that timing. Same as above:

```
{ "Install" => ["foo", "bar"], "Breakdown" => ["blah", "cat"], "Fuel" => ["jimmy", "cricket"] }
```

### In your view

Last, in your view, you can use the `titles_by_timing` method as the `grouped_options_for_select` to get the title. This will work for both the **Nested Array** and **Hash of Arrays** routes.

```
f.select :title, grouped_options_for_select(DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing)
```

Comment: first, thank you for the awesome response. Until you posted I had considered the different ways this was possible looking at the ruby documentation but this is just amazing. However, I am getting an error 'unexpected keyword end' when i attempt to add your method. not sure why..

Comment: If you were using the second one (hash of arrays), it's because you just discovered a typo in my code. I fixed it in my answer, but all you need to do is remove the `]` I accidentally had in there.

Comment: it was the array one.

Comment: I've added both and still see the same error. I am being a total dunse here sorry. I added my model if you dont mind taking a look. thanks again

Comment: No problem. You don't want that method to be private (because it needs to be accessed in your view), but I don't think that will fix the error. I'm looking into it further. Can you add the full error?

Comment: I moved the method to my controller from where I can inspect it. It works. Could it be there is something up with self (at least the method is splitting it into an array). I'll post the error message now.

Comment: [The error means](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13500576/2856441) that you're missing an `end` in your file. It doesn't seem like you pasted the full model, because the error message happens at line 43, but the model you pasted has fewer than 43 lines. Can you either double check that you aren't missing an `end` in something else, or paste the whole file?

Comment: the weird thing is if I comment out your method it works. line 43 is the last line in my model file. the reason you might see fewer is that I have been fiddling around. I'll repost. Added

Comment: Oh god, total brain fart. Add `def` before the name of the method. Hardcore misprint. Sorry about that. I've updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: hahaha, oh man. I tried that but I thought you must have known. I feel  dumb now. I dont get it. I am getting error undefined method even though its defined in the model and I am calling it in the view like this = f.input :title, grouped_options_for_select(DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing)

Comment: I think you want `f.select`, not `f.input`, although I don't know if that will fix it. Which method is it saying is undefined? `titles_by_timing` or `grouped_options_for_select`?

Comment: titles_by_timing, i changed. Its so weird. I have done this quite a few times before (I am a few months in to my rails odyssey)

Comment: Wait so did changing it work for you? If not, can you make sure the function is still not under `private`?

Comment: yup done all that, still no cricket. Man, thank you so much for going through this with me.

Comment: I tried in the rails console. [1] pry(main)> DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing
NoMethodError: undefined method `titles_by_timing' for #<Class:0x00000106f397b8>
from /Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'I must have missed something major here.

Comment: Is the method commented out still? Are you sure it's available? Can you make sure your model file is saved with the method starting with `def`? That would be my only thought... It'll be available if it's defined correctly.

Comment: Yeah, i've reposted but this makes no sense. any way. thank you again. I'll let you know when I get there

Comment: You need `def self.titles_by_timing`

Comment: No problem! I messed up too, so definitely don't worry about it hahaha. Are you all set? Is it working correctly?

Comment: Yeah man. Its there. How i imagined. Now ive got to mess about wit the values it passes. But that feeling of relief...   Oh god, soo good.

Comment: Well I'm glad I could help you out! And I definitely get that sense of relief. Struggle 99% of the time for the 1% relief and accomplishment. Let me know if I can do anything else for you.